What is the quietest propeller aircraft in the GA category?
Among all propeller aircraft in General Aviation which one has the lowest noise level (from outside the aircraft)?
Wondering what makes it quiet(is it just the prop, are there other factors, etc)?

Are you willing to consider Human-Powered Aircraft?  With no engine or exhaust noise and a big, (comparatively) slow-moving propeller, these are probably unbeatable.  If you want not just a propeller but also an internal combustion engine, then that's a different consideration.

@RalphJ I didn't see that one coming, indeed that could be the quietest of all time. I want to limit it to the GA category....updating post.

How  strict are you on the concept of GA?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_YO-3_Quiet_Star

@RobMcDonald that one definitely qualifies even though it has a military mission I think it well suited to be on the GA world, very interesting one...

Does the propeller have to be in use?  A motor glider with the engine off and propeller retracted would be quieter than a human powered aircraft with the propeller turning.

Are you asking about the noise inside the aircraft or the noise on the ground?

@AnonymousPhysicist yeah, that would desqualify it, it wouldn't be fair to compare it to others either.

@AnonymousPhysicist outside, people hearing it from outside...updated post.

No solid noise data available, therefore only as a comment and not an answer, but from the design those two should be contenders: Solar Stratos and HY4.

@PeterKämpf Although solar and fuel cell electric aircraft will have essentially no engine / motor noise (though electric motors can have a high pitch whine from their inverter), unless the system was specifically designed to be quiet, the propeller will be a significant source of noise.  Efficient, lightweight props have heavy blade loading and have high tip speeds -- quiet props have light blade loading and tip speeds as low as possible.

Although it was never commercially available, the Lockheed YO-3 Quiet Star was a Vietnam observation aircraft designed to fly at 1000 ft agl undetected at night.
It was based on the Schweizer SGS 2-32 glider and used a Continental IO-360D.  Later versions used a constant speed wooden propeller.  It was equipped with an elaborate exhaust system to help silence engine noise.

So quiet, it was used as a noise measurement platform for other aircraft
